# What are XQD memory cards?

Tags: memory-card

I noticed that the [Nikon D4](http://www.nikon.com/news/2012/0106_flagship_01.htm) uses XQD memory cards along side Compact Flash memory cards. What are the differences or advantages of XQD?

Comment: This was downvoted... why? Feel free to msg me in chat.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe someone figured you could better get the answer from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQD_card

Comment: @mattdm - Good point. I always forget about Wikipedia for photo stack exchange! Quite a bit of the info in the answer wasn't in wikipedia at the time of writing anyways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XQD is an open format created and licensed by the CompactFlash Association. The interface is based on the PCI Express or PCIe specification, a standard for serial interfaces. The specification was announced on Dec 7th, 2011 [in this press release](http://compactflash.org/2011/compactflash-association-announces-the-recently-adopted-xqdtm-specification-as-a-new-memory-card-format/).

The first camera to be announced that uses the format is the Nikon D4. [Nikon claims](http://www.nikon.com/news/2012/0106_flagship_01.htm) a write speed of up to 125MB/s or 1Gbps in the D4, although this has not been tested independently as of yet. They also claim up to 125MB/s or 1Gbps read speed.

Currently, only 16GB and 32GB capacities are available, through the Sony H Series of XQD cards.

Other specifications noted by the CompactFlash Association:

- Size of the cards: 38.5 x 29.8 x 3.8mm
- Interface performance potential: PCI Express 2.5Gbps currently, 5Gbps future
- Durable & Robust

As a comparison to Compact Flash, the XQD format isn't necessarily faster, but the interface has the potential to be much faster. For example the [Lexar 1000X CompactFlash card](http://www.robgalbraith.com/bins/content_page.asp?cid=7-11673-12230) claims a read speed of 150MB/s and write at 145MB/s, but current cameras can't keep up with this speed as most do not support UDMA7. The Nikon D4 according to the Sony specs [released](http://www.sony.net/Products/memorycard/en_us/xqd/index.html), can keep up at 100 continuous RAW shots.

Comment: Which Nikon D4 spec? Information obtained from Nikon says 90 RAW or 170 JPEG for continuous shooting.

Comment: @Itai - That is based on the info here: http://www.sony.net/Products/memorycard/en_us/xqd/index.html The ref says "*2 When used with Nikon "D4", with capture of compressed 12-bit NEF (RAW) images. Based on Nikon research." Does that jive or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: Oh, OK. That is not what Nikon gave to the press but it may be a firmware difference based on when the test was conducted. We will know the truth when the camera ships :)